# Recreate android activity without blink

Tags: android

Whenever I call recreate() in the android activity. The activity blinks and recreated. Is there any way to avoid this blink effect?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I clearly don't understand what you meant so:

- If you want to restore data when recreate() call, I suggest you to
  use [Mvvm].
- If the problem is something else, please put your code here.